# How to fix "t.hrtime is not a function" issue?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nativescript, aws-sdk

I'm working on a nativescript app that uploads file to AWS S3 bucket. Here's my current code:

```
const params = {
        Bucket: AWS_S3_bucket,
        Key: 'license',
        Body: this.licenseFileName,
        contentType : 'application/pdf'
    };

    let s3 = new AWS.S3({
        apiVersion: "2006-03-01"
    });

    s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('There was an error uploading your file: ', err);
            return false;
        }
        console.log('Successfully uploaded file.', data);
        return true;
    });
```

I used both "aws-sdk" and "nativescript-aws" but still I got this error:

> There was an error uploading your file:  TypeError: t.hrtime is not a function

How can I fix this?

**EDITED:**
I guess this is triggered because of the plugin I'm using which is "aws-sdk", but I'm not sure about that. Am I using an outdated plugin? or is there a workaround for this kind of error?

Comment: Where is the error triggered? That function call doesn't appear in the code in your question, is it being done by one of the calls you're making? If so, which one?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include in my post, I guess it is triggered because of the plugin I'm using which is "aws-sdk", not sure about that. Am I using an outdated plugin? or is there a workaround for that kind of error?

Comment: Again: Which call? :-) `new AWS.S3`? `s3.upload`? Something else?

Comment: I got these error: "There was an error uploading your file: TypeError: t.hrtime is not a function", so I guess its on "s3.upload"

Comment: By aws-sdk are you referring to `nativescript-aws-sdk`?

Comment: actually, I tried both "nativescript-aws-sdk" and "aws-sdk", but I got same error